# Angular 2 issue getting select option value

Tags: angular

I have a select

```
<select name='shape_id' ngModel (change)='changeShape($event.target.value)'>
  <option *ngFor="let shape of shapes" [ngValue]="shape.id">{{shape.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Here is the data.

```
  shapes = [
    {id:'1', name:'Angle'},
    {id:'2', name:'Bar'},
   ];
```

I can't get the value.

```
 changeShape(shape){
    console.log(shape);
  }
```

This outputs "0: 1", but I want the value 1.

Here is what the option looks like in inspector.

```
<option value="0: 1" ng-reflect-ng-value="1">Angle</option>
```

How do I get the id value 1?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change [ngValue] to [value]

```
  <select name="shape_id" (change)="changeShape($event.target)">
    <option *ngFor="let shape of shapes" [value]="shape.id">
      {{shape.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

and shape to shape.value.

```
changeShape(shape){
  console.log(shape.value);
}
```

Comment: I accidentally left out the .value in the original post and have since added it back...  thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, Fixed my problem in angular 5

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to subscribe to 'change' event unless you really want to perform some action when the value changes. But if all you want is to get selected value then it is enough to just bind it to the component property with ngModel.

Component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent {

    shapes = [
        {id:'1', name:'Angle'},
        {id:'2', name:'Bar'},
    ];

    shape: string;

    onSelect() {
        // log updated value
        console.log(this.shape);
    }

}
```

Template:

```
<select name='shape_id' [(ngModel)]="shape" (change)="onSelect()">
  <option *ngFor="let shape of shapes" [value]="shape.id">{{shape.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yeh i need to perform an action when it changes.  thanks

Comment: @AndrewThomas, I updated my answer. But still, even though you want to perform some action on value selection you still don't need to change the value manually. It is framework's job to provide you with data bindings, so let it do its job.